# How to debug with tiered compilation enabled?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, jit

I want to attach to java process with gdb with tiered compilation enabled. To attach at the specific instruction number by address I use print compilation as follows:

```
java -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:CompileCommand=print,Main.m Main
```

It prints something like this:

```
CompilerOracle: print Main.m
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: printing of assembly code is enabled; turning on DebugNonSafepoints to gain additional output
Compiled method (c2)      55    1             Main::m (1 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00007f25d506fc10,0x00007f25d506fdc8] = 440
 relocation     [0x00007f25d506fd38,0x00007f25d506fd40] = 8
 main code      [0x00007f25d506fd40,0x00007f25d506fd60] = 32
 stub code      [0x00007f25d506fd60,0x00007f25d506fd78] = 24
 oops           [0x00007f25d506fd78,0x00007f25d506fd80] = 8
 metadata       [0x00007f25d506fd80,0x00007f25d506fd88] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00007f25d506fd88,0x00007f25d506fd90] = 8
 scopes pcs     [0x00007f25d506fd90,0x00007f25d506fdc0] = 48
 dependencies   [0x00007f25d506fdc0,0x00007f25d506fdc8] = 8
Loaded disassembler from /opt/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/amd64/server/hsdis-amd64.so
Decoding compiled method 0x00007f25d506fc10:
Code:
Argument 0 is unknown.RIP: 0x7f25d506fd40 Code size: 0x00000038
[Disassembling for mach='amd64']
[Entry Point]
[Verified Entry Point]
[Constants]
  # {method} {0x00007f25d223c2f8} 'm' '()V' in 'Main'
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  0x00007f25d506fd40: sub     $0x18,%rsp
  0x00007f25d506fd47: mov     %rbp,0x10(%rsp)   ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - Main::m@-1 (line 10)

  0x00007f25d506fd4c: add     $0x10,%rsp
  0x00007f25d506fd50: pop     %rbp
  0x00007f25d506fd51: test    %eax,0xa7c82a9(%rip)  ;   {poll_return}
  0x00007f25d506fd57: retq
  0x00007f25d506fd58: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd59: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd5a: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd5b: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd5c: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd5d: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd5e: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd5f: hlt
[Exception Handler]
[Stub Code]
  0x00007f25d506fd60: jmpq    0x7f25d506c760    ;   {no_reloc}
[Deopt Handler Code]
  0x00007f25d506fd65: callq   0x7f25d506fd6a
  0x00007f25d506fd6a: subq    $0x5,(%rsp)
  0x00007f25d506fd6f: jmpq    0x7f25d50473c0    ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007f25d506fd74: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd75: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd76: hlt
  0x00007f25d506fd77: hlt
OopMapSet contains 0 OopMaps
```

and I can succesfully attach to the process using `gdb` and set a break on the instruction address specified in the output above.

But in case of tiered compilation however after setting breakpoint in `gdb` the app can never stop. I suppose this is because I set breakpoint and the code was recompiled at the next tier and placed at different address.

Is there a recipe to debug with tiered compilation enabled?

Comment: damn I love your questions!

Comment: So what is the problem? With TieredCompilation you do exactly the same, but having in mind there can be several compiled versions of the method. But all these versions will be printed, too. So you basically need to set several breakpoints to all methods.

Comment: yes, having a fixed address for your breakpoint is definitely a problem. since u are debugging the VM, i expect u also build it yourself. in this case i found it the easiest to find the location in the jit where the code u wanna debug is generated, and emit a 0xCC at that location. meaning u automatically insert a breakpoint into the code, u dont have to place it in a debugger.

Comment: @apangin when tiered compilation is enabled it prints two compilation indeed. But even with `-server` flag enabled the last one is still marked `Compiled method (c1)` so reasonbly I don't reach the breakpoint pointed to by the address. Maybe the next tier c2 compilation is not being printed...

Comment: `CompileCommand=print` prints both C1 and C2 nmethods. Probably, when tiered compilation is on, your target method is inlined into a bigger one, so you don't see it alone.

Comment: @apangin Is compiled code in steady state with tiered compilation enabled is the same as when it is disabled?

Comment: No. Moreover, even the same method may be compiled differently in different runs.